# HTML & Regex, how to match text inbetween commas with keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

Let us say we have  `<b>Location: </b> UK, England, London <br>`

To select this line with RegEx im using `(Location:+.*?<br\/?>)`, which is doing the job but what i need to do is return the three elements between the commas in seperate variables.

The variables are in javascript, like so.

```
var location = document.body.outerHTML.match(/(Location:+.*?<br\/?>)/gi);   //returns entire line with Location:**is working
var country = document.body.outerHTML.match(/(Location:[^,]*)/gi);         //returns UK, USA etc **is working
var state = document.body.outerHTML.match(/(Location:???;                  //needs to return 'England' etc 
var city= document.body.outerHTML.match(/(Location:???;                   //needs to return 'London' etc
```

I have successfully got the country by using `(Location:[^,]*)` this returns 'UK' as expected, but I really don't know how to amend it to return 'England' and then again to return 'London'.

I've seen some examples of how to select all commas, but can't find anything that helps me specify how to get the text after second and third commas, with the specific keyword of "Location:".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second regex will not return "UK" but "Location: </b> UK"

Comment: That's true, but I'm using `.replace("Location:", "")
 .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')
 .replace(/^(\s*)((\S+\s*?)*)(\s*)$/,"$2");` to clear up the results and it seems to be working well at the moment

Comment: Ok, but then the comment behind this line is misleading. Be nicer to you future self reading this code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var tmp = document.body.outerHTML.match(
    /Location: <\/b> ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+)/i
);

var country = tmp[1];
var state   = tmp[2];
var city    = tmp[3];
```

Updated to also match words with spaces between the commas.

Comment: Thanks for that, slightly confused as to how to get the results out. I'm currently using `if (country) { for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {  country[i] = country[i].replace(/&amp;/g,"&").replace("Location:", "").replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').replace(/^(\s*)((\S+\s*?)*)(\s*)$/,"$2");` Yes, I know its probably a mess, but am learning lol. Do I reference the variable 'country' or tmp[1]?

Comment: If someone could point me towards a good tutorial/article that shows you how you take the example above forward and get the results out, i would be forever grateful

Comment: You do not need the variable `country` at all, as it only references `tmp[1]`. To help you better you could put your code on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simplifying the problem by referencing from a parent element:

```
<div id='parentElement'><b>Location: </b> UK, England, London <br /></div>

var arr=document.getElementById('parentElement').childNodes[1].nodeValue.split(',');

var country = arr[0];
var state   = arr[1];
var city    = arr[2];
```

Comment: Thank you but there is no parent element to work off and I'm not able to add anything to the original html

Comment: what does the rest of the page look like?

Comment: Thanks the basic page can be seen as this jsFiddle

Comment: I thin you forgot to link your fiddle

Comment: If you can count on that html structure you could use: var arr=document.getElementsByTagName('font')[2].getElementsByTagName('b')[2].nextSibling.nodeValue.split(',');